# Invoke-WebRequest timeout if NIC 1 disconnected

Tags: networking, powershell

I have a windows pc with three network interfaces. One is a UMTS modem and the two others are lokal networks and one network has connection to the internet.

```
Invoke-WebRequest http://192.168.1.118/File1.xml
```

As long as i have an internet connection, either via umts or via the second network the Invoke-WebRequest works. But if i only have connection to one local network, i get a timeout, although pinging the adress is still working.

Where might be the problem? Or is it possible to define the network interface where the webrequest should try to get data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was actually a configured proxy which was the problem. As long as the internet connection was available the proxy was reachable.

Disabling the proxy solved the issue.

Answer (score 2):

Are you able to actually get a response from that address in a browser with only the local network connected?
Even if ping works, there may be other network issues blocking other protocols and ports. Examples are firewalls, NAT configuration, routing issues, etc.